# If element has same class after updating state in React.js, animation does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple demo. When you click a box which have `find` class, i shuffle `arr`.

If `find`box is at the same index after shuffled, it seems react does not reset it's class, because animation does't work.

**Why and how i can make it work?**

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/waapvct4/)

**Note**: Click `find` box and if `find` box will be at the same index, you see animation won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due the the very nature of what `React` does. This is actually a wanted behavior: "In case nothing change between the virtual DOM and the real DOM, then we'd better do nothing" :)

When the `found` index is the same as the previous index, well ... Nothing changes, so React does nothing and the init animation isn't played.

You need to find a way to tell React that something has changed on this element and that it needs to be updated on the DOM. The `key` property is often to way to do this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

Comment: BTW reading your code, I just realized the extra parameters of the `bind` method existed. Very usefull for React event handlers, thanks for that @norx :)